# Why browsers can receive incoming connections and other soft's cant!?

Tags: firefox, tcp, ip, port

my question is simple

When you send data through TCP/IP protocol with EX:firefox you can receive reply on some random port that the browser listen on, while when i try to use a port for another task like CS Gaming or anything else it don't work unless i use kind of VPN ?

PS: there r no firewall blocking connection and port forwarding from my router didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers are client apps that make outbound connections to web servers.  When connecting to a server through a router’s [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), the NAT takes note of the source and destination IP/port pairs so messages sent back from the server on the same connection are automatically routed to the correct client IP/port.

Browsers also support the [websocket protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). This feature makes it seem like the browser is listening on a specific port. However, in reality, it is initiated on a new connection to the server, a connection which remains open all throughout the websocket communication.

What matters is which peer is behind the NAT — the server or the client. For an outbound connection from a client, it can usually use any random port that is available at the time. For an inbound connection to a server, the server's IP/port must be known ahead of time and be routable. If the server is behind a NAT, the router(s) must be configured to make the server reachable from the other side of the NAT.

The server software can make a UPnP request to ask a router to forward inbound packets to the correct IP/Port. The router, depending on its configuration, may or may not honor such a request.  If not, the router has to be configured manually by a network administrator.